# I use POST method for form but echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] result is GET

Tags: php

i have a problem that is i use POST method to post my form but when i echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] the result is GET, why?
this is my code

```
<div align="center">

<form action="../application/components/check.php" method="POST" >

<table align='center' cellspacing='20px;' class='menubg'>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>
            <div style='height:30px;'></div>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right' style='color:#ffffff; vertical-align:middle; font-family:arial; font-size:13px;'>User Name</td> 
        <td align='left'>  <input type="text" name="uname" value="" onfocus="this.select()"/> </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='right' style='color:#ffffff; vertical-align:middle; font-family:arial; font-size:13px;'>Password</td >
        <td align='left'>   
                        <input type="password" name="pass"  value="" onfocus="this.select()"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2' align='right'>
         <input type='submit' value='ENTER'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>
```

On check.php, i write like

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
       //code
}
```

it wont go in that, after that i try

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ;
```

the result return `GET`.

I have try another pc to run this code, it ok, but come to my pc then cannot,
my pc using xampp,so any different, and how to solve it??

Comment: you using any JS/Ajax with this? I see some JS in here, which makes me raise a brow.

Comment: Server details please, and whether any htaccess or other restrictions in place

Comment: @DanielBrose you remind me a problem that is htaccess, after i delete .htaccess that is works! But why?

Comment: @ReiTee - share the contents of your htaccess in a clear update, also referancing that you read the post by Tim and saw that $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is a false-flag but not the answer to the OP.  Edit your original post, add a few <br/> and ** ** (see help for markup guide). I personally leave OP content, maybe adding a single line pointing people to the update at bottom if big post. Then add **Update** or **Edit** with new content at bottom, and add **Original Post** header on old content.

Answer (score 0):

That's because [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) contains the request method i.e. what method was used to access the page (which will be `GET` in nearly all cases where you're just requesting a webpage from a browser), NOT any `POST` or `GET` data that was submitted from a form. `POST` data that was submitted from a form should be interfaced with via `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Try if($_POST) to check if it's a POST. Since all pages have $_GET set, if($_GET) will not work. You can also try something like if(count($_GET)>0). That will tell you if there is any $_GET data.

Comment: Hi, i try like:
    if(count($_GET)>0){
     die;
    }

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
echo 123;
}else{
echo "get";
}

and the result will show "get"